# How to insert Oracle Collection data into CLOB Column of a table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, types

I have records in a collection variable. O want to insert all records into CLOB Column of table.

```
    set serveroutput on;
declare
    type ROW_DATA is table of varchar2(256) ;
    ROW_D ROW_DATA;
begin
    with DIFF_TAB_DATA as
    (
    select SOME_COLUMN from SOME_TABLE1
    union all
    select SOME_COLUMN from SOME_TABLE2
    union all
    select SOME_COLUMN from SOME_TABLE3
    union all
    select SOME_COLUMN from SOME_TABLE4
    union all
    select SOME_COLUMN from SOME_TABLE5
    )
    select SOME_COLUMN bulk collect into ROW_D from DIFF_TAB_DATA;
    insert into CLOB_TAB values(ROW_D);
end;
```

But I am getting the error that local collection variable can not be used in insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's a *mismatch*. The *local collection types* can't be replaced with the *data type* of the current value, those are totally unrelated. Rather call the collection along with an indexed set to extract the values stored in them. In order to perform this just replace

```sql
INSERT INTO clob_tab VALUES(row_d);
```

with

```sql
FORALL indx IN 1 .. row_d.COUNT
INSERT INTO clob_tab VALUES(row_d(indx));
```